# How to print the field with duplicate value in .txt file

Tags: shell, sorting, split

I have a file like this

**File**

124 3 ac 7

143 3 zf 10

176 8 lm 1

547 7 km 5

862 8 sf 6

991 7 zv 6

I want to create 3 different files from this with following output
**File 1**

124  3 ac 7

143  3 zf 10

**File 2**

176  8 lm 1

862  8 sf 6

**File 3**

547  7 km 5

991  7 zv 6

Please help me with the commands.

Comment: You mean that you want to have only 2 lines in each file?

Comment: @karan shah i have edited the post. it is a table with 4 columns and 6 lines

Comment: Are there any special characters then? Can I see the actual file?

Comment: No tere is no regular expression.\The file is too big to upload here but its a typical BLAST output and i need to separate the matches on the basis of query identity

Comment: Can I know what is a query identity? Do you want to just chop off two lines and keep in a different file?

Comment: Yes i need to keep all the lines which matches same database in separate files. query identity is different in each line

Answer (score 0):

> $awk 'NR>1{print $2,$3,$4 > $1}' File

This command did the work for me.
Thank You!!